# Not able to select multiple files in JFileChooser even with multi selection enabled

Tags: java

I have an application that should allow the user to select multiple files from a JFileChooser window and process them. When I ran this application last week, the JFileChooser allowed the user to select multiple files as one would normally (holding down ctrl or apple key and selecting files). However, I am trying to rerun the same application today, and the JFileChooser is not allowing me to select multiple files in the same way I did before. I have my multiselectionenabled(true) statement, and the FileChooser has worked before, so I'm very unsure about what happened. Here is the code:

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    System.out.println("Choose the files you would like to process.");
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(fc.getApproveButtonMnemonic()==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
        assert(files.length!=0);
    }else{
        System.out.println("You've opted to cancel. System will now exit.");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Inside for loop.");
            System.out.println("Chosen File: "+files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
  return files;  
}
```

It's very simple and it has always worked before, so I don't know why it is not working today. Could someone please help me fix this? This step is crucial in my program.

Comment: This line `if(fc.getApproveButtonMnemonic()==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)` shouldn't be `if(fc.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)`?

Comment: I've tried this code and it works for me. What OS do you use?

Comment: @dic19 You're right. I changed that line and it worked. I've just never written the code that way before. Thank you.

Comment: @YuriiShylov You're right, by default `fc.getApproveButtonMnemonic() == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == 0`. I just checked it and it worked. I'm on Windows 7 by the way. However I think the right comparisson would be using the value retrieved by `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog()` method and `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION` constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this block:

```
fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if(fc.getApproveButtonMnemonic()==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
    assert(files.length!=0);
}
```

You're comparing the Approve button Mnemonic (that could be `null`) with an integer constant (`JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`). It should be:

```
//fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if(fc.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
    assert(files.length!=0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why it was working last week though, but thank you!

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry. I may have spoken too soon. With this edit, even though I can SELECT multiple files, only the first file I select is processed. The way I can tell is that my program creates directories for each selected file, and only one directory is produced (which is for the first file I selected). Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the code where you're processing selected files? Your new problem shouldn't be related to the suggestion I made at all, it should be something else. Please post some more code and I'll be glad to help you.